# Understanding LDAP Responses simulating them with c# code

Tags: c#, ldap, tcplistener

I need to simulate a LDAP directory to send predefined responses to one application that needs LDAP to work. I am making some test using LDAP Browser and LDAP Admin listening to the 389 port. To write the response I would use a NetworkStream and StreamWriter. From the LDAP RFC I have the model showed below for a search response. I can't figure out how to build this envelope, do I have to build a byte sequence?

```
SearchResultEntry ::= [APPLICATION 4] SEQUENCE {
                objectName      LDAPDN,
                 attributes      PartialAttributeList }

        PartialAttributeList ::= SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE {
                type    AttributeDescription,
                vals    SET OF AttributeValue }
        -- implementors should note that the PartialAttributeList may
        -- have zero elements (if none of the attributes of that entry
        -- were requested, or could be returned), and that the vals set
        -- may also have zero elements (if types only was requested, or
        -- all values were excluded from the result.)

        SearchResultReference ::= [APPLICATION 19] SEQUENCE OF LDAPURL
        -- at least one LDAPURL element must be present

        SearchResultDone ::= [APPLICATION 5] LDAPResult
```

I got the request that the client is sending, I can identify the string part of the request, but I didn't find the correct way to answer back. By the strings found in the request I can figure out what kind of message the client is sending.

```
public static void Connect()
{
        try
        {
            int port = 389;
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                LDAPLayer handler = new LDAPLayer(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(handler.LDAPListener));
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
}

public void LDAPListener()
{
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");

                while (line != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                    if (line.Contains("objectClass"))
                    {
                        writer.Write(0);
                    }

                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is not a textual protocol. Each LDAP message must be encoded using BER rules according to the X.690 specifications.